# Node Acl dynamic links

Tags: javascript, node.js, acl

I'm trying to use the npm module Acl to implement an ACL system. The homepage can be found here: https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl.

The documentation shows a lot of very simple examples for giving a role access. In particular, there is a good piece of code here:

```
acl.allow([
    {
        roles:['guest','member'], 
        allows:[
            {resources:'blogs', permissions:'get'},
            {resources:['forums','news'], permissions:['get','put','delete']}
        ]
    },
    {
        roles:['gold','silver'], 
        allows:[
            {resources:'cash', permissions:['sell','exchange']},
            {resources:['account','deposit'], permissions:['put','delete']}
        ]
    }
])
```

Unfortunately, the docs don't show any examples of a more complicated url like '/blogs/:id/today'. Is it possible to set acls for these kinds of dynamic urls?

And, I also need to specify that only certain users can get their own information. This means that 'users/:id', should only work if the user's id is the same as that of the url. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Their docs do cover this, unless I'm missing something.  Taken from their README:

> The middleware accepts 3 optional arguments, that are useful in some
>   situations. For example, sometimes we cannot consider the whole url as
>   the resource:
>
> ```
> app.put('/blogs/:id/comments/:commentId', acl.middleware(3), function(req, res, next){…}
> ```
>
> In this case the resource will be just the three first components of
>   the url (without the ending slash).
>
> It is also possible to add a custom userId or check for other
>   permissions than the method:
>
> ```
> app.put('/blogs/:id/comments/:commentId', acl.middleware(3, 'joed', 'post'), function(req, res, next){…}
> ```

Comment: So this portion refers to how you can change the middleware when we are checking a given user. But, I'm trying to figure out how to let joed's role allow '/blogs/:id'. It's not clear to me how the joed's role was set up in the first place

Comment: @Paul,@ritmatter
Can we authorize for the urls like `'blogs/:id' , 'blogs/:id/details/:commentID'`
where both of them have **different authorization** levels for **different users** ?

Comment: Given that this question is now nearly 6 years old and you're asking something that wasn't covered in the original query, @ChaitanyaBabar you might want to open a new question

Comment: @Paul
Sure I guess need to open the new one.
Would be great if you only let me know whether it is possible to handle above case with given url using node acl ?

Answer (score 0):

Although docs do say that node acl supports for the dynamic urls here. But after looking at the source code **we do not find** any reference which supports the access to the dynamic urls.

There is also an **open github issue** here https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl/issues/192 which points the same.

Although we can implement our own middleware filters to support for the dynamic urls , but I guess instead of that it should be fixed in node acl library itself.

**Conclusion:-** Node ACL library does not supports for urls with params (i.e. dynamic urls).
But if we still want to use Node ACL library for dynamic urls the suggestion from the https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl/issues/192#issuecomment-226761840 can be used.